# How to Deploy .net MVC project with its database from localhost to live hosting

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, web-hosting, publishing

I have a running .net MVC project which is connected to MS SQL and its database is created using connection string. Now I want to deploy this project to live hosting.
I already tried to deplot my project using publish method through ftp but it did not work for me. I think the problem if of the connection with IIS server with SQL on my hosting.I am uploading code of my project's connection string which is now on localhost.
Kindly guide me how can I deploy project from localhost to live hosting?

Thanks in Advance

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Ratings" connectionString="data source=GDIT-22\SQLEXPRESS;  initial catalog=Ratings;persist security info=True;     Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Where are you deploying to? Did any files get deployed? Did you get any error messages? What is your hosting environment?

Comment: my local files has been deployed to live hosting but after performing each step I get the 500 error. like when I run my domain I got 500 - Internal Server Error. I think its DDL on web.config issue. Guide me how to get rid of this?Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you double checked your IIS config? If all your files are deployed and you can't get the site to run it probably isn't a connection string issue.

Comment: I am still unable to find any solution of 500 error